# What number can I increment by to produce a sequence of unique numbers over a finite range?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sorry... wasn't sure how to put a simple title on this so anyone who can update it to something better please feel free to do so.

Consider the following sequence:

1,4,7,0,3,6,9,2,5,8

Starting at 1, it adds 3 each time and subtracts 10 whenever the result would be equal to or greater than 10. By doing this I can produce a sequence that hits each number between 0-9 before any of them get repeated.

I'd like to do this over a much larger range, and with a much larger incremental value. The range would be more like 0 to 2,000,000. And the incremental value should be greater than 10,000 (preferably greater than 100,000).

How can I find this number to increment by that will allow me to hit all values between 0 to 2,000,000 using the same type of sequence described above except instead of dropping 10 when it gets to 10 or more, I would drop 2,000,000 when it gets to 2,000,000 or more?

Comment: Anything that is coprime to the modulus will do.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I guess I'll be looking up what coprime means now :)

Comment: $k$ and $n$ are coprime if $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Comment: Just chiming in to say that Daniel is 100% right

Comment: Ok, that didn't make any sense but I looked it up and found in layman's terms what the coprime is.  Now... what are you calling the modulus here? I understand what the modulus 'operator' does but not sure I know what you're referring to.

Comment: The modulus in this case is $2000000$.

Comment: Which btw, I'm a software developer who hasn't had a math class since I took calculus in high school about 14 years ago. So while I'm a good problem solver, I'm definitely not on your level so I need simple explanations!

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks! You guys are awesome :)

Comment: One last question: the modulus is 2,000,000 if I'm starting at 0 or if I'm starting at 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try it, with your example of $10$, you could use increments of $1,3,7,9$. Similarly, any increment that is coprime to $2,000,000$ will do what you want. Pick any number that doesn't have a factor of $2$ or $5$.